Wireless Debugging is disabled when I disconnect the USB
I am connecting my mobile device with the laptop using the following commands
adb tcpip 5555

adb connect ip_address:5555

The connection is successfully established and it shows wireless device in the VS Code devices. But the problem is as soon as I disconnect the USB. The devices disappear, even the wireless one.
I tried restarting my device, killing server and starting it again but no help.

Actually, for some reason it worked when I enabled "Allow ADB debugging in charge only mode" in developer option.
